# No module named 'bcolors' although 'Requirement already satisfied'

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to use `bcolors` in my python code in Spyder/Anaconda but it keeps telling me
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcolors'`.

So I installed it with `pip install bcolors`which gave me `Requirement already satisfied: bcolors in e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.4)`, but it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install lower version of this module
pip install bcolors==1.0.2

Comment: Why do you think this makes it possible to import `bcolors`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the pandas' library using  *`pip install pandas`*

Comment: When `pip install pandas` I get `Requirement already satisfied` for pandas, numpy, python-dateutil, pytz and six.

Answer (score 0):

You had that error because you are in different interpreter trying to import the module. You should append the path of the module to your working directory.

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("\anaconda3\lib\site-packages")

import bcolors
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Apart from that, from consulting the output of `print(sys.path)` it's already part of the path variable. Should there be a directory `bcolors` in that path? There is a directory `bcolors-1.0.4.dist-info` but no `bcolors`.

Comment: Can you copy and past the absolute path of **bcolors** here?

Comment: From Spyder I get the following:
Requirement already satisfied: bcolors in e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.4)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the latest distribution as well. Installing 1.0.2 worked for me.